# Servlet containers create Servlet Request/Response objects or HttpServlet Request/Response objects?

Tags: java, servlets

Whether the servlet container creates a ServletRequest & Response objects or Http ones? If it is ServletRequest, who transforms the same into HttpServletRequest before calling the service method?

50% of the articles that I've read go with ServletRequest; the other 50% with HttpServletRequest.

Thanks

Comment: Of course the container creates HttpServletRequest and response instances. What else could? You realize that HttpServletRequest extends ServletRequest, right?

Comment: Yes, I know what extends what. I got confused because SCWCD book by Manning publication says that it's Servlet Request/Response objects. Also, a number of online articles say the same.

Comment: If you know that HttpServletRequest extends ServletRequest, then you know that a HttpServletRequest **is a** ServletRequest. If you're confused about a specific sentence in a book and want our advice, you should quote the sentence in the question and tell us what confuses you.

Comment: Here it is : "The servlet container calls the service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) method of HttpServlet."  This is from pg 35 of 2nd Edition SCWCD, Manning publication.

Comment: That is completely correct. The documentation is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html. You see that this method indeed has ServletRequest and ServletResponse as arguments. That doesn't mean that the container doesn't call it with instances of HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse. If you read the documentation, you'll see that it does. And that's fine since HttpServletRequest **is a** ServletRequest, and HttpServletResponse **is a** ServletResponse. A road accepts vehicles. You can go on a it with a car:  a car is a vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

An `HttpServlet` receives `HttpServletRequest/Response.`

Some other hypothetical kind of servlet, hereuntofore never seen in captivity, might receive some other kind.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the ServletRequest and ServletResponse objects will be created by container, Then these objects will be passed to public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res) method. This method will change these objects into HTTP type which are nothing but HTTPServletRequest and HTTPServletResponse objects. These objects will then be passed into protected void service(HTTPServletRequest req,HTTPServletResponse res) method. this method will then transfer request to doGet() or doPost() methods. All these are methods of HTTPServlet class.

Answer (score 0):

The container never creates the `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` objects because these are interfaces and hence cannot be instantiated. Instead what the container does is that it creates the objects of the classes implementing these interfaces depending upon the type of request.
So if the request is for an `HttpServlet`, it creates the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects which are downcasted to same in the `service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)` method of `HttpServlet` class and passed to its overloaded `service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)` method.
You can check the source code of HttpServlet class here -
https://github.com/javaee/servlet-spec/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java